# RRD with a high-precision?

Tags: c, linux, rrd

Is it possible to use RRDs with a high-precision? And by high-precision I mean e.g. in the range of milli-seconds.

If not, are there equally good alternatives to RRD with a C API that work under Linux?

Comment: Doesn't rrdtool do what you want? You can compile against librrd.

Comment: No, in the source code it is stated "step size should be no less than one second".

Answer (score 0):

the step size in rrdtool is an integer and thus can not be less than a second. BUT updates can carry a ms precision time stamp and will be handled correctly. It is just that you can not store samples more often than once per second.